# Can I use VBA in excel to keep a cumulative total based on a letter in a cell and that cell being highlighted yellow?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, iteration, highlight

I've trying to create a rota for shift workers and I can't really get my head around how to do it but some pointers would be much appreciated.

Basically, for each row in a table I would like to check if that cell is highlighted yellow and if it contains a E, L or D to add 8 to the total and if it contains a W to add 12 to the total.

I understand there's no way to use Excel to perform this function but there might be a way to do it in VBA.

Does anyone have any tips I could use please?

Many thanks

Comment: I would strongly recommend you use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables to edit a text table with some sample data into your question. Also, does the yellow reflect some data? Or is it unrelated to the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the UDF below in Module and use it as the usual Excel function in cell formula [=TotalSum(A2:H2)]. But color change of cells will not fire recalculation. Press Shift+F9 to recalc the sheet or F9 (whole workbook)
Also you san use this code in other sub not as UDF

```
Public Function TotalSum(rng As Range) As Double
    Application.Volatile    'recalculates with any calculation on the sheet
    
    Static a    ' static variables hold it's values between function call
    If IsEmpty(a) Then a = Split("E:8:L:8:D:8:W:12", ":")   'initially fill
    
    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then    ' check if color is yellow
            txt = cl.text
            For i = 0 To UBound(a) Step 2       ' check if text contains defined symbols
                If InStr(1, txt, a(i), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    TotalSum = TotalSum + a(i + 1)  'if yes, add correspondent value
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Function
```